# Prohibit the creation of React elements

Tags: reactjs

I have working code that helps me create a to-do list. The code works well. But alas, even when I accidentally send an empty form, the elements continue to be created. How with useState it is possible to cause the message on prohibition of sending of the empty form and with the request to fill ?? Can you show an example? Thank you

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";

export let Tasks = () => {

let [tasksList, setTasksList] = useState([]);
let [nameOfTask, setNameOfTask] = useState('');
let [termOfTask, setTermOfTask] = useState('');

let createTask = (isInput, termOfTask) => {
    let newTask = {
        id: Math.random().toString().substr(1,90),
        task: isInput,
        term: termOfTask
    }
    setTasksList([...tasksList, newTask])
}

useEffect(() => {
    setTasksList(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tasksList')) || []);
},[])

useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('tasksList', JSON.stringify(tasksList));
},[tasksList])

 let getValueNameOfTask = (e) => {
    setNameOfTask(e.target.value)
}

let getValueOfTaskTerm = (e) => {
    setTermOfTask(e.target.value);
}

let taskCreated = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    createTask(nameOfTask, termOfTask)
    setNameOfTask('');
    setTermOfTask('');
}

let taskFinished = (id) => {
    setTasksList(tasksList.filter(todo => todo.id !== id))
}

 return (<div className="tasks_page">

    <div className="form_part">
        <form onSubmit={taskCreated} className="form_of_new_task">

            <label>Нове завдання</label>

            <input
                type="text"
                id="name_of_task"
                placeholder="Нове завдання"
                onChange={getValueNameOfTask}
                value={nameOfTask}
            />

            <input
                type="text"
                id="term_of_task"
                placeholder="Термін виконання"
                onChange={getValueOfTaskTerm}
                value={termOfTask}
            />

            <button onClick={taskCreated} id="submit">Створити</button>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div className="tasks_to_do">

        <h1>Список завдань до виконання : {tasksList.length}</h1>
        <div>{tasksList.map(el => <div key={el.id} className="different_task">
            <h1>{el.task}</h1>
            <p>{el.term}</p>
            <button onClick={() => taskFinished(el.id)}>Finished</button> </div>)}</div>

    </div>

        </div>)
}
```

Comment: Don't create and add the new task if it's invalid, set something indicating an error, and use that to render an error message? I'm not sure what specific issue(s) you're having.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't sound like it has anything to do with React, just normal JavaScript.

If this is the operation you want to conditionally perform:

```
createTask(nameOfTask, termOfTask)
```

Then wrap it in a conditional:

```
if (nameOfTask !== '' && termOfTask !== '') {
  createTask(nameOfTask, termOfTask)
}
```

Then it would just silently not do anything unless values are present.

---

If you also want to show the user a message, *that* is more of a React concern.  Then you would track the display of that message in state.  For example:

```
let [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('');
```

And display that message in your JSX somewhere:

```
{ errorMessage.length > 0 ? <span class="error">{errorMessage}</span> : null }
```

Then simply update that error message in your conditional check:

```
if (nameOfTask !== '' && termOfTask !== '') {
  createTask(nameOfTask, termOfTask);
  setErrorMessage('');
} else {
  setErrorMessage('All fields required!');
}
```

It essentially follows the same pattern as nearly everything in React:

- Define State
- Render based on State
- Update State where appropriate

Comment: Thanks you very much)